# How to extend ByteArrayComparable and write myown CustomHBaseComparator hbase0.96?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

We are storing `data(int,long,double,string,float)` in HBase as string.
For comparison/filter we have done `customComparator` by extending `WrittableByteArrayComparable`.

Now we have upgraded our cluster from  CDH 4.3.0 to CDH 5.0.1 successfully.
But, we have noticed  `WrittableByteArrayComparable` is no longer available and we are asked to use `ByteArrayComparable` instead as per docs.

Any sample implementation using below signature will be helpful.

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter.SingleColumnValueFilter(byte[] family, byte[] qualifier, CompareOp compareOp, ByteArrayComparable comparator);
```

How to retrieve the data from underlying HBase is what I all need.

Earlier we have used `WrittableByteArrayComparable` and overridden below mentioned methods, that are handy to do our `customFiltering`.

```
@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    setInputValue(Bytes.readByteArray(in));
    setDataType(in.readUTF());
}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    Bytes.writeByteArray(out, getInputValue());
    out.writeUTF(getDataType());
}
```

Now I am struck with getting same functionality with `ByteArrayComparable`.